# How do I create rDNS (Reverse DNS)

Tags: linux, dns, centos, ip, reverse-dns

How to create rDNS (Reverse DNS), I am using Centos 7.0 and I need to create rDNS for 50 IP's and domain.

Can you please guide me how can I create.

Example.

```
Example.com - xxx.xxx.xxx.xx0
Example.xyz - xxx.xxx.xxx.xx1
```

Thank in advance

Comment: What DNS server are you using?

Comment: I am using Cloud dedicated server. And i have installed Centos, can you please provide me guide to create rDNS or any command

Comment: Are you using [Bind](http://bind9.net/), or something else?

Comment: Sorry but i dont have much knowledge about bind and creation of rDNS. This is my first time with Reverse DNS. Can you please help me how do i proceed and what i need.

Comment: you must have forward DNS before you can set up reverse DNS. Look into setting up **Bind** https://www.howtoforge.com/bind-installation-on-centos

Comment: Ones i installed Bind, can i use bind to create rDNS of Multiple Ip's and different server IP's

Comment: yes, once bind is installed you can create forward and then reverse zone definitions.

Answer (score 1):

The only person who can set a reverse DNS is the owner of the IP addresses, such as the service provider who purchased them in large block quantities. I don't think it's something most internet or server customers have access to. You have to open a ticket with your provider and ask them to do it for you on their systems.

A description of the problem:
http://support.simpledns.com/kb/a100/how-do-i-get-reverse-dns-for-my-ip-addresses-delegated-to-my-own-dns-server.aspx

A technical explanation of how your provider would handle this on their end, if they wanted to give you full control:
http://support.simpledns.com/kb/a146/how-to-sub-delegate-a-reverse-zone.aspx

Comment: Hello, I already created ticket and get replied, They said it a unmanaged detecated server, i have to care about it. They will not create